# How can I return the index of mid in my recursive binary search program?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, binary-search

```
class Solution: 
    def binarysearch(self, arr, n, k):
        # code here
        first = 0
        last = n - 1
        mid = (first + last)//2
        if(arr[mid]==k):
            //Here
        elif(k > arr[mid]):
            self.binarysearch(arr[mid+1:n], len(arr[mid+1:n]), k)
        elif(k < arr[mid]):
            self.binarysearch(arr[0:mid], len(arr[0: mid]), k)
        else:
            return -1
```

I can't figure out how to get the index of mid as I am manipulating the array in every call. The parameters of the function are fixed, I can't give the first and last parameters to the function. I tried using the iterative approach and I got it but I am not able to do it like this. I just want the logic to get the index of mid in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To get index of middle element in array you can pass an additional parameter(eg. start_index in below code) to function that keeps track of the starting index of current subarray

```
class Solution: 
    def binarysearch(self, arr, n, k, start_index):
        # code here
        first = 0
        last = n - 1
        mid = (first + last)//2
        if(arr[mid]==k):
            return start_index + mid  # Return the index of mid in the original array
        elif(k > arr[mid]):
            return self.binarysearch(arr[mid+1:n], len(arr[mid+1:n]), k, start_index + mid + 1)
        elif(k < arr[mid]):
            return self.binarysearch(arr[0:mid], len(arr[0: mid]), k, start_index)
        else:
            return -1
```

Comment: Its a question in a contest and we cant modify the parameters. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Jeevani6607 are you allowed to use iterative approach for binary search? If yes, then you can keep track of the index using separate variable

Comment: Yes, I solved it using the iterative approach. So, there isn't any way to track the variable like this?

Comment: Is using a global variable to store the index of the current element being searched( in recursive approach )allowed? then I might have an alternate solution